# PHP/MySQL get number of not null column in a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get ONE row using my sql query.

I want to count how many column of this row are not "NULL" or "", Is there any way to do this using MySQL?

Comment: Generally speaking, the semantic meaning of each column should be different... so discovering how many share a particular property (e.g. contain NULL or empty data) is pretty meaningless.  If it's meaningful to you, it suggests that your schema is denormalised.

Comment: Each column have same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$row = array(0=>"abc", 1=>NULL, 2=>"NULL"); // assuming that $row is the row fetch from database

$null_count = 0;
$not_null_count = 0;
foreach($row as $val)
{
  if($val=='NULL' || $val==NULL)
  {
     $null_count+=1;
  } 
  else 
  {
    $not_null_count+=1;
  }  
}

echo "Null Count :".$null_count;
echo " Not Null Count :".$not_null_count;
```

See **[Demo](http://codepad.org/aVdTUbU5)**

Comment: Here is un update with my code : http://codepad.org/letZRDly but it didn't work, it give me answer I don't know where from.. are they anyway to replace $val by $row[*] or something in that direction

Comment: Here is un update? means?

Comment: Well I mean Here you can find where the raw come from, I'm not sure of if the raw format is the same as yours ?

Comment: print you raw and give me the output.

Comment: You can find it here http://tinypic.com/r/4ruw7r/8

Comment: Your solution work just have to divide by 2 the result no idea why ;)